# iTunes Store Operation Failed ERROR ITMS-90159: "Invalid provisioning profile...."

Tags: xcode, error-handling, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

Unfortunately I have a problem, when uploading my app... here is the situation:
I built an iOS App for a client, but he wants to upload the app via his Developer account. He created a provision profile and added me to his team on iTunes connect (admin).

But when I wanted to upload my app to the App store (in xCode) the following error showed up:

This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID XXXXXXXX."

What do I need to do? Do he has to give me more rights on iTunes connect/Apple Developer? Have I installed the provisioning profile wrong?

Thank you very much in advance, I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Have you selected the correct team in your project settings?
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Art/3_assignteam_ios_2x.png

Comment: Also, adding you as a team member in itunes Connect will not give you access to the code signing files (certificate and profile) needed to sign the app under your client's team.  He needs to add you as a role on the Apple developer account. See the Apple Developer Program Team Roles here: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: @wottle Thank you very much for your help. So the problem is I can not select his team in my project settings, because he has not added us as a team role in the Apple Developer program, right? After this I would be able to select the right team ?

Comment: You should, yes.

Comment: @appleUserK Do you solve the problem? I have several questions...

Comment: @SergeyDi Yes, you need to have a premium or enterprise Apple Developer plan. Otherwise it is not possible

Comment: @appleUserK Thank you. I solved the issue by adding iTunesConnect account to Xcode over teamviewer app. So I provided access to uploading apps without admin access to iTunesConnect. (in Xcode password stored as hash)

Comment: "He created a provision profile and added me to his team on iTunes connect (admin)." DO you have a P12 given by the client as well to let you install the profile in your Xcode. In your keychain check if the cert is there with tree opened and shows the private key as well. Just installing the Cert and Profile will not do if you dont have the p12 for it. Also you need to ensure the ItunesConnect is up with all this info feeded first before you initiate the upload.

Comment: Note only AGENT Login can upload the app to Itunes / Appstore, not the ones who are given Admin access. This privilege is just for you to add more team members or create and modify profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to the question is in my case that this is only possible with the Apple Developer Agent plan. Then you another Person can add you as a role on the Developer Portal and you are able to upload the project on his name.